# How to setup Eccp2 With a timer and ZeroCross

Tags: c, mplab

How to setup `Eccp2` With a timer and `ZeroCross`.
I need to figure out how to open-close an output with comparison the timer and eecp2.
I need to make a motor to work from 25% up to 75%.

I have include Eccp2 and Timer1 and Ext_INT Libraries from mplab. I have set ECCP2 to compare `timer1`. Also `Ext_Int` to falling `Edge` in input `INT0`.

So the first thing in my main which i'm trying to do is to set interupt everytimer i get zerocross. I dont know if i explain it well...
I mean every time that the input in INT0 is in Ground.

```
INT0_SetInterruptHandler(ZeroCrossCallback);
```

Second i found a code which i dont know exactly what its doing...

```
void ZeroCrossCallback() {
    if (!PORTBbits.INT0) {
    TMR1_WriteTimer(0);
    CCP2CONbits.CCP2M = 9;
    EXT_INT0_risingEdgeSet();
} else {
    CCP2CONbits.CCP2M = 0;
    EXT_INT0_fallingEdgeSet();
    }
}
```

And last I need to set my motor to work from 25% up to 75%

[Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHUFN.jpg)

Comment: It would be better to inline the image.

Comment: I dont know how can i do that

Comment: Click 'edit' below the question, then either the 6th Icon (Image) in the toolbar above or press ctrl-g. Clicking works better for me as Opera uses ctrl-g for text search.